# lsof all /tmp/serverlist.lock and jboss error too many open files

Tags: jboss, db2

I use JBoss EAP 5.1.2. In Linux, I got error of "too many open files". Then I used `lsof` to look file handle, I found:

```
java 16752 ch_as  582u REG 202,3 0  1573210 /tmp/serverlist.lock
```

there are **8690** rows for the above file,  is it too much?

I want know ,what is `/tmp/serverlist.lock` and how I fix it?

DB: DB2  9.5.7
Linux: SUSE
JBoss: JBoss EAP 5.1.2

Answer (score 1):

serverlist.lock is file that DB2 JDBC driver creates and uses for its operation.

There is some talk about it in [release notes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC74457) for jdbc driver.

All I could recommend you is to use latest Type 4 JDBC driver(if not already) and if problem still persists ask IBM support about it.